# Cancel script script execution from C++ in a web browser control application

Tags: javascript, browser

I am designing an application which hosts IE's web browser control. It will run a lot of javascripts from within the webpages. Poorly written javascript can easily hang the entire application. Let's say I can detect the script-induced hanging. Is there any C++ COM method I can call to cancel the script execution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can stop JavaScript (running in the browser) from the application (c++), pretty sure you can only stop JavaScript execution with JavaScript.  Also, there is no event that is triggered when JavaScript is hanging, or causing the browser to be unresponsive, so detecting this would be very difficult.